# Is there any way to increase the gap between text and underline in Excel?

Tags: excel, text, between, underline

I know that there is an option for doing this in MS-Word but I didn't find anything for Excel neither on google tightener in Excel's Format Cells and Font Properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get close by Setting superscript and increasing the font size. But I do not see how to control the size of the gap.
[image]